# single-line macro existence check (ifdef) in a NASM 0.98.39 multi-line macro

Tags: nasm

I'm using NASM 0.98.39 (an old version) to assemble the following test source file:

```
%macro M 1
  %ifdef A_%1_B
    %error OK
  %else
    %error undef
  %endif
%endm

%define A_foo_B
M foo
```

I want `OK` because `A_foo_B` is indeed a defined single-line macro. In NASM 2.13.02, it displays `OK`, however in NASM 0.98.39 and NASM 0.99.06, it displays `undef`. How can I make it work with NASM 0.98.39?

Please note that upgrading NASM is not an option for this project, and inlining the macros `M` wouldn't scale, because there are thousands of macro callers, and some abstraction is needed.

FYI If I change it like this, it stops working in NASM 2.13.02 as well, with the error message *`%ifdef' expects macro identifiers.`*:

```
%macro MS 1
  %ifdef %1
    %error OK
  %else
    %error undef
  %endif
%endm

%define A_foo_B
MS A_foo_B
```

Even more stranglely, these both display `OK` (as expected) in all the above versions of NASM:

```
%macro MH 1
%ifdef %1_B
%error OK
%else
%error undef
%endif
%endm

%macro MT 1
%ifdef A_%1
%error OK
%else
%error undef
%endif
%endm

%define A_foo_B
MH A_foo
MT foo_B
```

Comment: `%ifdef %1` doesn't work in any NASM version because the %1 parameter will be fully expanded at macro invocation time, first to A_foo_B and then that to the empty string. So the %ifdef gets an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This workaround of defining 2 macros works in all versions of NASM mentioned in the question:

```
%macro MT 1
%ifdef A_%1
%error OK
%else
%error undef
%endif
%endm

%macro MIND 1
MT %1_B
%endm

%define A_foo_B 1
MIND foo
```

This needs a major refactoring of existing NASM macros using `%ifdef` though.